# Why am I getting a 406 error when trying to get JSON in Java Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, controller, response

When I usually make controller endpoints with Java Spring that return JSON data, my return type is usually `String`; I'll `toString()` my JSON objects and parse them in my Javascript. Recently, I read somewhere that that wasn't the "correct" way to do it (trying to follow best practices and guidelines). I am starting a new project where my return type is a JSON object (dependency is `org.json`).

When I try to hit the endpoint in the browser, I'm getting a 406 error with a description of "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.".

Here is what my endpoint looks like now:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/get-items", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject doGetItems(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray items = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject item1 = new JSONObject().put("id", 123);
    JSONObject item2 = new JSONObject().put("id", 456);
    JSONObject item3 = new JSONObject().put("id", 789);
    items.put(item1).put(item2).put(item3);
    data.put("data", items);
    return data;
}
```

How can I get this to work and return JSON? Or am I supposed to be returning a stringified version of my JSON object and I was doing this correctly all along?

**Update**

First, I tried taking out the `headers` parameter in the `@RequestMapping` annotation. I still got a 406 error.

I then tried changing/adding the parameters in the `@RequestMapping` annotation, with no luck as well. This is what I tried changing it to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/get-items",
                method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST},
                headers = "Accept=*/*",
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

I'm still getting a 406 error.

Comment: Un didn't understood correctly. Spring doesn't deal with instances of org.json.JSONObject. It uses Jackson (or GSON, depending on what you have in your classpath) to automically parse/marshal from/to actual Java classes. So, if you want to return, for example, an array of projects, where each project has an ID, a name and a startInstant, for example, then just return a List<Project>. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ for an official example.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried changing all of the `JSONObject`s and `JSONArray`s in one of my endpoints to `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`, using gson, but then got a 500 error saying "Could not write JSON: This is not a JSON Primitive."

Comment: Again, read my comment. You shouldn't return JsonArrays or JsonObjects. You should return POJOs, that will be mapped to JSON. As shown in the example I liked to.

Comment: Easy. I did read your comment. Part of it said "or GSON" so I tried `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`.

Anyway, I understand now in terms of using Java objects. If I `toString()` the JSON objects I constructed with `org.JSON`, Spring in fact does take care of the rest and return them as actual JSON. I'm fine with that; just a misunderstanding on my part.

if you submit your response as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) **406 Not Acceptable** client error response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

**Proactive content negotiation headers include:**

A client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) can indicate to the Web server (running the Web site) the characteristics of the data it will accept back from the Web server. This is done using 'accept headers' of the following types:

**Accept:** The MIME types accepted by the client. For example, a browser may only accept back types of data (HTML files, GIF files etc.) it knows how to process.

**Accept-Charset:** The character sets accepted by the client.

**Accept-Encoding:** The data encoding accepted by the client e.g. the file formats it understands.

**Accept-Language:** The natural languages (English, German etc.) accepted by the client.

**Accept-Ranges:** Whether the client accepts ranges of bytes from the resource i.e. a portion of the resource.

By changing or removing header content at client side it should work.

Comment: Updated original post. I tried taking out the `headers` parameter in the `@RequestMapping` annotation, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `headers = "Accept=application/json"`, then you're saying that an `Accept` header must be present and have exactly that value.

The client didn't send exactly that value, and there is not reason it should be required to do so, because the `Accept` header value is a comma-separated list of acceptable values, so it just needs to list `application/json`, it doesn't have to *only* specify that value.

To fix, replace `headers = "Accept=application/json"` with `produces = "application/json"`.

Of course, the client still needs to specify that `application/json`, `application/*`, or `*/*` is acceptable.

Comment: I updated my original post. I added `produces = "application/json"`, as well as added `headers = Accept=*/*`, but that did not work as well.

Comment: @aCarella Remove `headers =`. That what the *replace* in my answer means.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work either. I figured out what the issue was. When you use @ResponseBody in Spring, you don't necessarily have to construct actual JSON objects and arrays. Java data structures can be used and returned with controller methods and they will be automatically converted.

In my case, if you do construct JSON objects and arrays with org.json, you have to turn them into strings being that Spring doesn't handle them. It's kind of like double work because Spring already uses Jackson to JSONify objects.

Comment: @aCarella So the very first [comment by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483481/why-am-i-getting-a-406-error-when-trying-to-get-json-in-java-spring/51484451?noredirect=1#comment89935928_51483481) was exactly right, huh?